# Improving the efficiency of my FizzBuzz algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ruby, programming-challenge, complexity, fizzbuzz

I worked on an [exercise from codewars](http://www.codewars.com/kata/514b92a657cdc65150000006), which is a variation of the popular fizzbuzz game.  (If the link doesn't work, you may need to reload the page.)

In this variation, I'm supposed to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than the passed in number.

My code works, but it's horribly inefficient. It only works for smaller numbers and can't work for really large numbers

```
def fizz_buzz_sum(number)
  (1..number).to_a.select{|x| x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0}.reduce(:+)
end
```

I think my problem is that I'm iterating over all the numbers in a large array and I might not have to.

Can anyone help reduce the complexity of my algorithm?

Comment: It appears that you have misinterpreted the Codewars exercise, so I've closed this question to prevent further confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not really a fizz-buzz problem at all, it is a sum-of-sequence problems, and is commonly based/equivalent to the [first "Project Euler" challenge](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)

**Note**: your code has a bug, you are supposed to sum values that are a multiple of either 3, or 5, but you are summing only the multiples of both 3 and 5 (i.e. 15) that are less than the number...

There is an algorithmic/mathematical solution to this which completely removes the need for the iteration at all.

Consider the sum of all the multiples of 3 less than `n`....:

```
3 + 6 + 9 + .... + t
```

where t < n.

The sum of that sequence is called the sum of the [Arithmetic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

if you change the sequence to be:

```
(1 x 3) + (2 x 3) + (3 x 3) + .... + (m * 3)
```

then you can factor out the 3's, and have:

```
3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + .... + m)
```

Now, the '1 + 2 + 3 + .... + m` sequence is what's called a triangular number:

```
*
* *
* * *
....

* * * .... *
```

which you can visualize as being half the area of a rectangle, where one side of the rectangle is `m`, and the other side is `m + 1`

What is the size of `m`, well, it is the number of 3 multiples there are:

```
m = (n - 1) / 3
```

And, your arithmetic progression sum becomes:

```
count3s = (n - 1) / 3
sum3s = 3 * count3s * (count3s + 1) / 2
```

Similarly, the sum of 5's less than n are:

```
count5s = (n - 1) / 5
sum5s = 5 * count5s * (count5s + 1) / 2
```

So, the sum of all 3 and 5 multiples less than n is easy, but there's a probem.... if we add the two sums together, it will count the multiples of 15 twice.....

so, the sum of one 15's series is:

```
count15s = (n - 1) / 15
sum15s = 15 * count15s * (count15s + 1) / 2
```

if we subtract that, you get the actual sum....

In ruby terms, this can all be reduced to a simple function, and then simple arithmetic... ([see ideone](http://ideone.com/8tFOY4) ):

```
def sum_series(base, limit)
    count = (limit - 1) / base
    sum = base * (count * (count + 1)) / 2
end

def fizz_buzz_sum(number)
  sum_series(3, number) + sum_series(5, number) - sum_series(15, number)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- The problems says "multiples of 3 or 5", so ||, not &&.
- `(1..number).to_a.select`. This `to_a` is unnecessary, class `Range` includes module `Enumerable`, so it has already a `select` method.
- `select{|x|2*x}`: The convention is to give some breathing space to blocks: `select { |x| 2*x }`.
- `.reduce(:+)`. Imagine there were no items to reduce, that would return `nil`. Just add the identity value of the operation: `.reduce(0, :+)`.
- If you used [lazy](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/4/3/ruby-2-0-works-hard-so-you-can-be-lazy) objects (Ruby >= 2.0), you wouldn't generate any intermediate array. This is Ruby, this kind of computations will never be fast, but now, at least, `number` can be arbitrarily large without you running out of RAM.

I'd write:

```
def sum_of_multiples_of_3_or_5(max)
  1.upto(max).lazy.select { |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.reduce(0, :+)
end
```